# I don't understand a simple JavaScript 'while loop'

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm currently learning JavaScript on [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/) and I am at the end of the while loops section.

The following code:

```
j = 0;
while (j < 3) {
    j++;
}
```

produces a `2` on the console and I have no clue why. I tried running this on `Eclipse` `JaveEE` only to realize that using a HTML file with this code as a script gives me a different result: a blank page.

That makes sense to me, because I've only incremented `j` to `3`, but not printed it. Not sure why the CodeAcademy console gives me a 2.

This is a screenshot of the console output:

[image: codeacademy console output]

Comment: Is this the full code? you are returning 2 at some point, hence it is appearing. Your while loop has no console statements to print on console.

Comment: where is console.log() statement in code

Comment: It's just a console that returns the value of the last expression. The behaviour is extremely tricky, so it's better to not think of it at the moment.

Comment: @virendrao there should not be one - a console outputs some value in every case.

Comment: Maybe the codeacademy console is taking the value of the last sentence. When the last `j++` is executed, the expression itself is evaluated to 2 because the evaluation of a post-increment operator returns the value of the variable before the increment. After the execution, `j` is equal to 3, but the evaluation of the last sentence is 2.

Comment: @JMSilla That makes sense according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k41698(v=vs.94).aspx                    since it mentions both a J++ and a ++J that changes the time of the increment happening.

Comment: For the record JavaScript does not naturally print to an html page so putting this on a page in a `<script>` tag won't give you anything at all unless you explicitly call `console.log(j)` and watch the JavaScript console. Codecademy prints the last expression of your code to its console as part of its evaluation of your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you're observing is because that's how a browser console works.

For every code you evaluate it tries to return some value. For trivial expressions it's easy - `2 + 2` would presumably return `4`.

For code that consists of multiple statements it's much more complicated and console tries to be smart. What adds more complexity into this is the fact that console's behaviour is not standardised, so what we observe at this very moment for a given browser is not guaranteed to hold true for another browser or for another release of the same one.

Let's try to find out what is happening though:

```
j = 0;
while (j < 3) {
    j++;
}
```

for this code browser tries to be smart and outputs the value of the latest found expression, which is in this case is `j++;`. It returns `2` because that was the value of `j` on the last iteration before loop termination. And since the postfix increment returns the current value before modifying it - it returns `2`.

If we change it to

```
j = 0;
while (j < 3) {
    ++j;
}
```

the output would be 3, for the very same reason.

Now let's try something different:

```
j = 0;
while (j < 3) {
    j++;
    a = 42;
}
```

this would output `42`. Since the `a = 42` is the latest expression in this code.

```
j = 0;
while (j < 3) {
    j++;
    var a = 42;
}
```

For this sample it would again return `2`, since console decides to ignore the assignment statement and reverts back to the latest expression.

To summarise: this behaviour is not standardised, and browsers just try to be useful and to output something, even if it's not what you expect to be. So my advice would be to not rely on the implicit console output and use the `console.log()` explicitly in case when you want to get a result.

Comment: The console isn't really trying to do anything clever. It's just giving the result of the `eval()` that is being performed.

Comment: @squint it's not required to return a result of `eval()`. Btw, it would be curious to see a corresponding implementation in browsers.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that they're required to. I'm just saying that that's what they're doing (most likely anyway) instead of trying to perform clever analysis tricks. The source code would be interesting.